# Strat extracting after a repeated string in regex

Tags: regex

How to extract `string_with_letters_and_special_caracters` in this sequence ?

`sequence_one \n sequence_two \n sequence_three \n string_with_letters_and_special_caracters 0000000 \n sequence_four`

I can't manage to beginning after the last `\n` preceding `string_with_letters_and_special_caracters`.
(Here \n is the repeated string.)

For example `\\n(\D+)\d+` extract from the first `\n`.

Example : I want to extract `- Dimensions : L.` or `Dimensions` here, which precedes an expression I have a pattern for :
https://regex101.com/r/jLqxxo/1

Thank you!

Comment: Are these literal `\n` or line breaks? Also after how many repetitions do you want to extract a substring?

Comment: So, `-\s*Dimensions\s*:\s*L\.\s*(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)`? See https://ideone.com/XiOHOp

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want

```
-\s*Dimensions\s*:\s*L\.\s*(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jLqxxo/2%5C) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XiOHOp):

```py
import re
s=r'''FICHE TECHNIQUE\n- Pieds du canapé en bois.\n- Assise et dossier en polyester effet velours.\n- Canapé idéal pour deux personnes.\n\nCARACTERISTIQUES TECHNIQUES\n- Dimensions : L. 128 x l. 71 x H. 80 cm.\n- Hauteur d'assise : H. 47 cm.\n- Poids : 15,14 kg.\n\n'''
m = re.search(r'-\s*Dimensions\s*:\s*L\.\s*(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)',s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => 128
    print(m.group(2)) # => 71
    print(m.group(3)) # => 80
```